# Insert PHP variable into SQL Select query output

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dynamic php variable that I would like to join to every row in a column of an sql query. I know that the following works to add as static variable:

```
$output = "SELECT
'example' as extra_column,
order_date as order_date
FROM $order_table"
```

would return:

```
extra_column     order_date
example          01/01/2017
example          02/01/2017
example          02/01/2017
```

but I cant figure out how to make the field in the extra column dynamic, for example I've tired

```
$output = "SELECT
'"$dynamic_variable"' as extra_column,
order_date as order_date
FROM $order_table"
```

but this breaks the query, anyone got any ideas?

Comment: what is the error you get ?

Comment: You don't need to alias every column. The alias here `order_date as order_date` is redundant.

Comment: `$output = "SELECT '$dynamic_variable' as extra_column, order_date as order_date FROM $order_table"`

Answer (score 2):

Try with dots to concatenate the string.

```
$output = "SELECT '".$dynamic_variable."' as extra_column, order_date as order_date FROM $order_table"
```

Comment: dots not necessary variables expand automatically in a double quoted string literal

Comment: Right but if you add the quotes it becomes necessary. I usually leave it in " with {} around it to increase readability.

Comment: `{}` only necessary if you are using a non scalar variable

Comment: Single quotes have no effect on the outer double quoted string literal thay are just another character

Comment: @RiggsFolly you are right, but since OP did put some double quote around his variable dots are now required. He needs add the dots or remove the double quotes inside the string. (like in your comment above +1)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196055/insert-php-variable-into-sql-select-query-output/42196093?noredirect=1#comment71554264_42196055

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error.

There should be dots when you concat string and variable.

```
$dynamic_variable = 'example';

$output = "SELECT
'" . $dynamic_variable . "' as extra_column,
order_date as order_date
FROM $order_table";
```

Comment: dots not necessary variables expand automatically in a double quoted string literal